# Is it possible to rank a model using acts_as_votable by the number of friends who voted up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Questions relates to the acts_as_votable gem.

I know you could sort Posts (for example) in order by using `Post.order(:cached_weighted_average => :desc)`but could I find a way of ranking Posts by the number of a user's friends who had upvoted a post?

I could do something like `<% @posts_ranked_by_friend_likes = current_user.friends & Post.get_upvotes.voters %> <%= @posts_ranked_by_friend_likes.size %>` and it would display the number of friends who voted up on that post but how would I be able to turn something like this into a ranked list?

Answer (score 0):

**you need to check whether user has posts...if yes,then check which posts have been liked and then return those posts...try this ...you can add friends and modify the below method**

**in user.rb**

```
 acts_as_voter
 acts_as_votable

def all_posts_liked_by_others
  @posts = Array.new
  //check if user has posts
  if self.posts.present?
    //reload posts/votes to get latest 
    self.posts.reload.includes(:votes).each do |p| 
    //check which posts have been liked/disliked
    if p.likes.count > 0
        @posts << p
    end    
  end
  //return the liked posts
  return @posts.compact.flatten.uniq
else
return @posts.compact.flatten.uniq

end

end##method ends
```